# Angular-seed scope issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angular-seed

I am currently trying to create a post that runs before each routeProvider.  Currently I am receiving an issue that $http is undefined and I don't know why.  I am currently trying to pass $http to the function and according to phpstorm $http is 'undefined' and don't know why.  I do declare angular.js before validation.js in the index.html.

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="components/universal/validation.js"></script>
```

And my app.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.test',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider','$http', function($routeProvider,$http) {
    alert ('before call');
    var temp = sessionValidation($http);
    alert('temp : '+temp);
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

Components/universal/validation.js

```
function sessionValidation($http) {
alert('before post');
return $http({
    url: 'http://255.255.255.255/rip.dll/REST/SESSIONS/',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType:"json",
    xhrFields :{"withCredentials" : true},
    data: {'logintype':'1','host':'255.255.255.255','user':'Administrator','password':'1234','controlid':'ABC999'}
})
    .success(function (data) {
        return data.stats;
    })
    .error(function () {
        return 'Error';
    });
}
```

And the browser displays this:

[image]

And here is the error message.

> [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $http http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24http at Anonymous function (http://localhost:90/angular-seed/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4284:13) at getService (http://localhost:90/angular-seed/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4432:11) at invoke (http://localhost:90/angular-seed/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4461:9) at runInvokeQueue (http://localhost:90/angular-seed/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4379:11) at Anonymous function (http://localhost:90/angular-seed/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4388:11) at forEach (http://localhost:90/angular-seed/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:336:11) at loadModules (http://localhost:90/angular-seed/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4369:5) at createInjector (http://localhost:90/angular-seed/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4294:3) at doBootstrap (http://localhost:90/angular-seed/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1655:5) at bootstrap (http://localhost:90/angular-seed/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1676:5) http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider%3A%20%24http%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.5%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524http%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A90%2Fangular-seed%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4284%3A13)%0A%20%20%20at%20getService%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A90%2Fangular-seed%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4432%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A90%2Fangular-seed%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4461%3A9)%0A%20%20%20at%20runInvokeQueue%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A90%2Fangular-seed%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4379%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A90%2Fangular-seed%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4388%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A90%2Fangular-seed%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A336%3A11)%0A%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A90%2Fangular-seed%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4369%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A90%2Fangular-seed%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4294%3A3)%0A%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A90%2Fangular-seed%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1655%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A90%2Fangular-seed%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1676%3A5)

Any help or point in the right direction why $http isn't set would be helpful.  Thank you.  If you need any other info, please let me know so I can update question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$http` service can't be used in `config` phase, as the provider might not be ready yet. What you can use here is the `resolve` property in `$routeProvider.when()` method:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/view1', {
            resolve: {
                sessionValidation: function($http) {
                    return sessionValidation($http);
                }
            }
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}])
```

Comment: Will that run before the routeProvider renders the view?

Comment: @SariRahal I'm not sure. But it should. `run()` is called immediately after all the service providers are initialized. You can try that out, I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: This doesn't run every time a new view is requested.

Comment: @SariRahal Ok. There is something called `resolve` in `$routeProvider` configuration, which is called before rendering view.

Comment: @SariRahal Can you try the updated code? I've added the route config for `/view1`. You can modify your config accordingly - `myApp.view1`.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of 'resolve' within angular-seed.  Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89100/discussion-between-sari-rahal-and-rohit-jain).

Comment: You've to define that `resolve` property in both your `view1.js` and `view2.js` files.

Comment: ok, it seems to work all but one thing.  it validates, but it only renders view1 every time.

Comment: @SariRahal Have you configured all the views? I don't see `myApp.view2` imported there. Are you trying to use that?

Comment: Yes, I just removed some of the code so it was cleaner for stackOverflow.  I have put that code back, as well as updated your answer with what I have.

Comment: @SariRahal You don't have to reconfigure the `/view1` and `/view2` in `app.js`. They are already configured in `view1.js` and `view2.js`. Just define `resolve` property in those files. I've just put it here to give an idea.

Comment: thank you.  It wasn't what I was thinking, but it got me to where I needed to be.  I was more looking to avoid having the same code in every routeprovider.

Comment: @SariRahal Take a look onto this - http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/04/javascript-angularjs-resolve-routes/, to remove duplication

Comment: @SariRahal Check this out too: https://github.com/btford/ngmin/issues/23, you can move the session authentication code in a service, and inject it in `.config()`.

Comment: From what I have been reading, replacing this code with a Service is the way to go.  Thanks you, I will update my code with the proper answer when I get everything working.